# What's the best sleeping posture for humans?

Tags: physical-health

We all sleep in different ways. Some on side,some on back,some on their front sides. But which sleeping form would be the most efficient, providing maximum rest to the body and brain?

There is loads of pseudoscience gibberish on net,and nothing scientific,so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: It's a good question, but there isn't a clear answer to be found, unfortunately.  Due to a neck issue I have, I have done a bunch of reading and asked many different experts, from orthopedists to sleep specialists to physical therapists to cranial OMT experts.  It depends on many individual factors, so a simple answer to this question isn't possible.

Comment: The loads of pseudoscience gibberish were probably a clue. I don't think you're going to find more than opinions on this.

Comment: The answer is simple, the best sleep position is the one that give you the best sleep. Any benefits of sleeping in some other position are completely offset if they cause you to sleep less deeply.